# No more bubbling after a week

Tags: mead, stuck-fermentation

I have made mead a few times with perfect results. This time I tried a Cyser in a 1 gal batch. I followed a recipe that, based on the notes, had good results from others. 1 Gal of 100% apple juice, 2lbs honey, nutrient, and energizer, and using Lalvin 71B yeast. I did everything as he said, half of the nutrient and energizer day 1, then the other half day 2. It bubbled great for about a week, then it just stopped. I've waited for just over another week with no results. OG was 1.100, I haven't taken another reading yet, but wanted to know if I should pitch more yeast, or just leave it alone?

Answer (score 2):

The key thing with mead is that you need to learn patience.  It should not be done fermenting in a week or two.  Not even a month or maybe not even two months.  Leave it alone completely for at least a couple of months before even thinking about doing anything else to it.  Time fixes a lot of things, especially with mead.

Answer (score 0):

From my personal experience with wine and beer making, if the fermentation is stuck, it can be a few things, but it usually comes down to the yeast. Either it is too cold, and warming your brew can start it fermenting again. Too hot and the yeast can be killed off, and in some cases, the yeast itself can be faulty. If you think that the temperature is right then, I would opt for a new yeast.